# Python UTC to local

Tags: python, windows, server, local, utc

Python parse time from SharePoint UTC time. But it is +2 hours. How to change UTC to local time? I need this code to change to be functional, because someone else created it. Thanks.

```
def getDatumPrijave(self):
    datpri = self.extract_to_line_end('CREATION_DATE: ')
    d = datetime.datetime.strptime(datpri, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return d.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
extra_hours = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(datpri, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")  + extra_hours
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. 
Will that work on daylight saving time?

Comment: Yes, but I need daylight saving time and UTC don't support it.

Comment: How daylight could work if UTC don't have daylight saving with SharePoint, it not work? I just add +2 hours, but UTC still will work without daylight saving time. If you could explain how can work if I add just + 2, but before that didn't work daylight saving time. I am trying to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else? SharePoint UTC don't support daylight time saving. I need to change this code to work as local.